# Ag-Grid all errors shows as an ERR list I need to customize it

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I need a way to override this ERR list with customized messages depending on the error that occurred.

Update question

This happen when my api failed.

[image]

Comment: How do you even get it to have ERR everywhere? Never seen that. There's not enough information in your question for it to be answerable.

Comment: I update my question, that err happen when anything wrong happens in getrows method

Comment: let's say what you want to achieve is possible, then you will end up with a grid that contains the same error message in every row.

Comment: I remember, there was a bug in ag-grid, when loading spinner were shown in many rows. If I'm not mistaken it was in v.28 or v27. But now in v29 this is fixed and it shows only one loading row, which in case of error turns into 'ERR'.

Comment: no you are not getting me I need instead of have this list of Err list I need have one column with custom error message

Comment: Did you find out how to do this?

Comment: no not yet do you know the answer

Comment: same here! in vue 3

Comment: same error too, in vue 3 ag-grid 31 enterprise, any idea?